# How to use Terminal Services EasyPrint from a Server 2003 client

Tags: terminal-services

I'm trying to get EasyPrint to work from workstations running Windows Server 
2003, connecting to a Server 2008 TS pool.

I noticed that there is a RDP 6.1 client for XP clients.  I couldn't get that 
to install on the Server 2003 box.

I was able to install RDP 6.0 client for Server 2003.   However it appears 
EasyPrint isn't actually working in this case, as we are seeing that printers 
without local drivers are not being redirected to the remote desktop.

Information on the web on this topic is somewhat conflicting.  Is what we 
are trying possible?   If yes.   Any suggestions on how to get it to work 
from a client on a  Server 2003 workstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pubforum.info/welcome/BLOG/tabid/78/EntryID/6/Default.aspx
This will do is for you :-)
Kim

Comment: The original link has gone 404.   Here is the content thanks to the wayback machine - http://web.archive.org/web/20081025070554/http://www.pubforum.info/welcome/BLOG/tabid/78/EntryID/6/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Terminal Server Easy Print Overview: 
http://winplat.net/post/Terminal-Server-Easy-Print-Overview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Installing the XP version of 6.1 will work for 32-bit Server 2003, but it doesn't work for 64-bit versions of Windows 2003.